# How to make radial gradient on each face using shader in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, gradient

using simple shaders I've found a way to create gradients.
Here's result of my job:
http://goo.gl/A7pY01 (A little updated after [OpenGL ES 2.0 Shader - 2D Radial Gradient in Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654149/opengl-es-2-0-shader-2d-radial-gradient-in-polygon)  question)

It's nice, but I still need to display this gradient pattern on **each face** of my meshes. Or on the **billboard** face, just like it's a texture.

The glsl function `gl_FragCoord` returns window-related coordinates. Could someone explain me the way how to translate this into face-related coords and then draw my pattern?

Comment: How are you setting up the texture coords for your mesh? You can use `gl_TexCoord[n]` (where `n` is the texture unit).

Comment: I have no texture in this example.

Comment: You don't need a texture to set texture coordinates. You can still set texture coordinates for each texture unit on every vertex. This allows you to control them however you need and use them in your shader, even if you never end up sampling a texture.

Comment: Could you spread your answer, or give example?

Comment: In order to do that, we need more information about how you're drawing your geometry. Are you using legacy code in immediate mode? VBOs? What version of OpenGL are you dealing with?

Comment: I can adapt your answer to my needs.  At least, you could give me certain restrictions of your method, or explain why should I be warned about terms you wrote in last comment.

Comment: There is no way to translate the window-space coordinate into something "face-related". That is what vertex attribute interpolation was designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey. A little surfing of `stackoverflow` gave me this topic: [OpenGL: How to render perfect rectangular gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359258/opengl-how-to-render-perfect-rectangular-gradient?rq=1)

Here is the meaning string: `gl_FragColor = mix(color0, color1, uv.u + uv.v - 2 * uv.u * uv.v);`

Of course we cannot translate window-space coordinates into something "face-related", but we could use UV coordinates of a face. So, I decided, what if we have a square face with uv-coordinates corresponding to full-sized texture (like 0,0; 0,1; 1,0; 1,1);  So the center of a structure is 0.5,0.5. This could be a center of my round-gradient.

so my code of fragment shader is:

```
vec2 u_c = vec2(0.5,0.5);

float distanceFromLight = length(uv - u_c);

gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(1.,0.5,1.,1.), vec4(0.,0.,0.,1.), distanceFromLight*2.0);
```

Vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = _mvProj * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
uv = uv1;
```

Of course, we need to give correct UV coordinates, but the point is understood.

Here's example:
http://goo.gl/A7pY01